# Confusion about Zipf's law; meaning of frequency and its PMD

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

In papers about Zipf's law* I often read, that the rank-frequency relation

$$
n (r)
$$
is a power law (asymptotically),  $n \sim r^{-\alpha}$.

We can also talk about the probability mass distribution for $n$ (treat it like a random variable and see how many times a certain frequency repeats) and obtain the probability of $n$ occuring, $f (n)$. **They claim, that asymptotically, $f (n)$ takes form of a power law, too and $f (n) \sim n^{-\beta}$ where $\beta = 1 + 1/\alpha$. How does one arrive at this result?**

Moreover, I am confused about the "frequency" itself. I was under the impression that the frequency is a number from 0 to 1 and denotes what fraction of times a word occurs in a text (so $n = 0.5$ would mean that it is every second word). But in these papers they treat $n$ as integer, how can that be the case? How can $n$ go to infinity? And why do they say that higher $n$ means the word is rarer? Clearly, if $n \sim r^{-\alpha}$, and if $r$ is the rank, farther ranks (rarer words) yield smaller $n$ and at some point $n$ cannot be even an integer. I think if I clear this confusion, I will be able to derive $f (n)$ from $n (r)$ and vice versa.

Some notes: the following bit is aligned with my intuition:

"*...the frequency of use $n$ of any word decreases with its rareness $r$... Technically, $r$ is called the rank, and the most common (i.e., less rare) word is assigned $r = 1$, the second most common, $r = 2$, and so on.*"

But in another sentence, this is directly contradicted:

"*When “rare” words are not considered (i.e., for high frequencies)...*"

so **do high frequencies correspond to rare or common words? And how can a frequency be any integer, what does small $n$ and large $n$ correspond to?** It would make sense to me that $n = 1$ corresponds to a word appearing only once in the text, $n = 2$ is a word that appears twice etc., thus $n$ would be small for rare words and large for common words. Moreover, I would expect $f (n)$ to be bigger when $n$ is small (there are many words that appear only once) and small when $n$ is large (there is less distinct words that appear same large amount of times). However, I still think that $n$ cannot be arbitrarily large. It is clearly bounded by the length of the text we're currently looking at. Moreover isn't there a problem with scaling? Let's say in a text with $10,000$ words, we have a frequency $n \approx 5,000$ appearing once for the most common word ("the"), but if we take a text that has $100,000$ words, we suddenly have $n \approx 50,000$ appearing once. I feel like the shape of $f (n)$ depends on the size of the text, so there would be no asymptoticality(?)

*i.e. arXiv:1509.04486v1